# Clicking on HTML <a> tag with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to click on html a tag with selenium but I get an error.

How can I get selenium to click on such tag?

I've tried this code but I get an error:

`driver.find_element_by_id("btnCreateJE").click()`

HTML code: 
`<a id="btnCreateJE" data-permission="true" onclick="NewManualJE()" href="@" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"> New </a>`

Python selenium code: 
`driver.find_element_by_id("btnCreateJE").click()`

I get that error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="btnCreateJE"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure that the element doesn't belong to the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), if this is the case - you will need to [switch_to_frame](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) first
2. Make sure that the element doesn't belong to the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), if this is the case - you will have to find the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) and locate your element relatively
3. It might be the case the link is not immediately present in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), i.e. it's being added later as a result of an [AJAX](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) call. If this is the case - consider adding [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) like:

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnCreateJE"))).click()
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "New"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.waves-effect.waves-light#btnCreateJE[onclick^='NewManualJE']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn waves-effect waves-light' and @id='btnCreateJE'][starts-with(@onclick, 'NewManualJE')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Eilon123 Tryout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately is doesn't work, any other ideas?